# data-item-url is on localhost instead of pythonanywhere (wagtail + snipcart project)

Tags: localhost, wagtail, pythonanywhere, snipcart

So instead of having data-item-url="https://miglopes.pythonanywhere.com/ra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%A3o-purina-junior-10kg/"

it keeps on appearing 
data-item-url="http://localhost/ra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%A3o-purina-junior-10kg/"

how do i remove the localhost so my snipcart can work on checkout?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details of where this tag is coming from it's hard to know for sure... but most likely you need to update your site's hostname in the Wagtail admin, under Settings -> Sites.